# How to get unique letter from CCLabelTTF sprite when touch moved in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have a  8x8 matrix of alphabet letters game,when I move touch into label,label value repeated,how to overcome this problem,letters are in random position in 8x8 matrix.

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
   CGPoint newlocation=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];

   newlocation=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:newlocation];
   for (int i=0; i<GRID_WIDTH; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<GRID_HEIGHT; j++) {
         if (CGRectContainsPoint([grid[i][j].letter boundingBox],newlocation)) {
            CCLOG(@"letters %@",[grid[i][j].letter string]);
            [letterarray addObject:[grid[i][j].letter string]];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem ? please clarify your question.

Comment: I'm getting repeated letters when moving touch through bounding box, like this:   B
  B
  B
  W
  W
  W
  W
  W
  W
  W
  W
  W
  I
  I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah ... too many touchMoved updates in a single grid element !  try this

```
     if (CGRectContainsPoint([grid[i][j].letter boundingBox],newlocation)) {
        CCLOG(@"letters %@",[grid[i][j].letter string]);
        NSString *thisLetter = [grid[i][j].letter string];
        if (![letterArray containsObject:thisLetter]) {
            [letterarray addObject:thisLetter];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"*** Skipping letter, [%@] already in the array",thisLetter);
        }
     }
```